# Why are my IE conditional statements not working?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, conditional-comments

I have the following:

```
  <!--[if IE]>
    <style>
      iframe {
        margin-top: 0 !important;
        display: none;
      }
      .c-position {
        margin-top: 20px !important;
      }
      br {
        display: none;
      }
    </style>
  <![endif]-->
```

But when I see my [site](http://www.carleighmac.org/) in IE10 The CSS within the IE conditional statements are not being applied (e.g. the iframe should disappear).

I even tied this:

```
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">
```

So IE10 recognizes the conditional statements.

Why am I doing wrong?

Comment: The real question here is why do you need to treat IE10 differently. Does the contents of your iframe not work near enough as well as it does in e.g. Chrome?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE10 does not support conditional comments.

[Source quote](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Support for conditional comments has been removed in Internet Explorer
>   10 standards and quirks modes for improved interoperability and
>   compliance with HTML5. This means that Conditional Comments are now
>   treated as regular comments, just like in other browsers.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps you can try some jQuery for ie10 like this:

```
if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 10) {
  $("html").addClass("ie10");
}
```

But surely it is not replacement for conditional comments!

Comment: [This question isn't even about jQuery](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19492/219504).

Comment: this thing adds class name ie10 if u r using ie10. its kinda solution